# Matching exact results in a comma separated column

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a column that contains comma separated ids such as:

| Id | ProductIds |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'ABC-123,1234,989123' |
| 2 | '123,XYZ' |
| 3 | '678,ABC-123' |

If I write a statement like

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ProductIds LIKE '%123%'
```

I would want this query to only return Row 2 because it is the only row that contains a CSV that is exactly `'123'`. However, understandably it also returns Rows 1 and 3 because it is matching `'ABC-123'` and `'1234'`.

What would be my best approach to solving this?

Comment: Add commas - you need to logically match on ",123,". That should be sufficient hint for you to implement. Or you can use a string splitter to match exactly using IN.

Comment: "Best"? We don't do best but you suffer from the decision to store CSV values in a column. Lack of normalization leads to these issues - can it be fixed?

Comment: You're gonna run into a whole lot of edge cases by pattern matching. I'd absolutely recommend using a string splitter

Comment: If you insist on pattern matching, check against `'123'`, `'123,%'`, `'%,123'`, `'%,123,%'` individually.

Comment: @SMor the database schema is completely out of my control. Trust me that was my first thought.

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't tag any specific SQL Server version, here's a solution that works in all versions of SQL Server, unlike `String_Split` which will require a higher version.

You could just put commas on both sides of the string you are searching for.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ',' + ProductIds + ',' LIKE '%,123,%'
```

Comment: Although this works, the problem here is it's not a sargable expression so the optimizer will be forced to do an index/table scan, this will be far less performant than a string-split method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `string_split`, something like

```
select t.Id
from MyTable
cross apply String_Split(productids,',')
where value='123'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`string_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. But it doesn't treat your data as CSV, so escaping will not work here. It is better to store this data in 1NF.

> ```
> with a as (
> select *
> from ( values 
>   (1, '''ABC-123,1234,989123'''),
>   (2, '''123,XYZ'''),
>   (3, '''678,ABC-123''')
> ) as t (id, productid)
> )
> select id
> from a
> where exists (
>   select 1
>   from string_split(trim(''''
>    from a.productid), ',') as f
>   where f.value = '123' 
> )
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=e419493d975e053f492b7e38f3d33858)*

Answer (score 0):

This checks All the conditions needed to extract comma related data from sql-server.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE
ProductIds = '123'
OR ProductIds LIKE CONCAT('%,','123',',%') 
OR ProductIds LIKE CONCAT('%','123',',%') 
OR ProductIds LIKE CONCAT('%,','123','%')
```